# Pytest run a final test on a shared fixture

Tags: pytest

I want to collect information from all my tests, to ensure that I've covered everything, but none of the posts I've come across seem to do this specifically.

If I use e.g. `atexit`, `sessionfinish` or other means mentioned when searching for "pytest function after all tests", I seem to lose the ability to use the fixture, and they seem like they're just teardown functions, rather than actual tests.

I want to be able to assert that 1 and 2 are in my fixture list, after running all tests.

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fxtr_test_list():
    return []


def test_something_1(fxtr_test_list):
    fxtr_test_list.append(1)


def test_something_2(fxtr_test_list):
    fxtr_test_list.append(2)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def global_check(request, fxtr_test_list):
    assert len(fxtr_test_list) == 0  # initial check, should pass

    def final_check(request):
        assert len(fxtr_test_list) == 0  # final check, should fail

    request.addfinalizer(final_check)

    return request
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixtures only in tests or other fixtures, so using a fixture in some hook is not possible.

If you don't need a dedicated test, you could just use the fixture itself for testing by making it an autouse-fixture:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def fxtr_test_list():
    return []
...

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def global_check(request, fxtr_test_list):
    assert len(fxtr_test_list) == 0  # initial check, should pass
    yield
    assert len(fxtr_test_list) == 0  # final check, should fail
```

Note that I changed the scope of the first fixture to "session", otherwise it cannot be used with sesssion-based fixture. Also, I have simplified the second fixture to use the standard setup / yield/ teardown pattern.

This gives you something like:

```
$ python -m pytest -v test_after_all.py
=================================================
...
collected 2 items

test_after_all.py::test_something_1 PASSED                                                                       
test_after_all.py::test_something_2 PASSED                                                                       
test_after_all.py::test_something_2 ERROR                                                                        

======================================================= ERRORS ========================================================
________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of test_something_2 ________________________________________

request = <SubRequest 'global_check' for <Function test_something_1>>, fxtr_test_list = [1, 2]

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
    def global_check(request, fxtr_test_list):
        assert len(fxtr_test_list) == 0  # initial check, should pass
        yield
>       assert len(fxtr_test_list) == 0  # final check, should fail
E       assert 2 == 0
E         +2
E         -0
...
============================================= 2 passed, 1 error in 0.23s ==============================================
```

If you really need a dedicated test as the last test, could could use an ordering plugin like `pytest-order` and mark the test as the last:

```py
@pytest.mark.order(-1)
def test_all_tests(global_check):
    ...
```